# Custom Policy to Enforce on Tag

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

I've trying to create a custom policy that will deny based on tag value. The tag is "`external VM`". The policy then allows a set of approved extensions to be deployed. However when I try to add the tag using `"tag.external vm"` it shows an error, which is the same as at the end of this essay (`The value of 'field' property 'Tag' of the policy rule must be one of 'Name, Type, Location, Tags, Kind, FullName, Identity.type' or an alias, e.g.`).

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "tag.External VM",
          "equals": "Third Party"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
          "notin": "[parameters('AllowedExtensions')]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "AllowedExtensions": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "AllowedExtensions",
        "description": "Allowed VM Extensions"
      }
    }
 }
}
```

The parameter file is

```
{
    "AllowedExtensions": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The list of extensions that will be Allowed.",
            "strongType": "type",
            "displayName": "Allowed extension"
        }
    },
        "tagName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The Referenced Tag Name.",
            "displayName": "Tag to Query"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to assign the tag name with the space in it. There other option was to have it re-tagged with "`external-vm`" or to parameterise the tagname such as

```
{
  "field": "[parameters('tagName')]",
  "equals": "Third Party"
},
```

But this gives me the error

```
The value of 'field' property 'Tag' of the policy rule must be one of 'Name, Type, Location, Tags, Kind, FullName, Identity.type' or an alias, e.g.
```

Any thought?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter was incorrect

```
"[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
```

adding it as a parameter resolved the tissue.

Comment: Adding it as a parameter works. You could also hardcode it like this: `"field": "tags['External VM']"`

Comment: @sapphiremirage thanks for the tip, really good idea as it’s a set value.